# Converting text containing COMBINING DIAERESIS to utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

We hav some text containing german umlauts represented using e.g. 'a' + COMBINING DIAERESIS
($cc $88).

Any idea how to convert such text properly to utf8?

Comment: So you have two code points, or you have some encoded form? Output the character to a UTF-8 stream, and it will be encoded. But see Ignacio’s answer about normalization. You probably want to normalize to NFC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if it's not already a `unicode` then decode it. Second, [`unicodedata.normalize()`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). Third, encode.

Comment: Specifically, you would want it in NFC form if you’re outputting it. NFD is more often used internally.